# What is best way to sync a sequence with CloudKit?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, cloudkit

I'm trying to use CloudKit to sync a sequence of items that a user creates. Think a TODO list that has a particular sequence.

My first thought is maybe to give each TODO a **position** property but I thought maybe that's not a good idea because when you sync from multiple devices, I'm not sure how CloudKit handles the merge. And then a missing or duplicate **position** will surely crash the tableView.

I thought maybe another way is to save a sequence of TODO id into a `[String]` but realistically the array will suffer from the same merge issues?

What is best practice?

Answer (score 1):

In one of my apps, I've taken the approach of adding a sequence property (position property as you say in your question).  When I make the query from CloudKit to get all of the items, I order by my sequence property and then everything shows in the right order in the tableview.

For editing/changing order, I use the MoveRowAt() function to allow the user to drag/drop and reorder items in the table (example below).

Once an object is moved, I run a for each loop to update the sequence property of all of the items to reflect the new sequence.

```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    let movedObject = self.headlines[sourceIndexPath.row]
    headlines.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
    headlines.insert(movedObject, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
}
```

Example above from: https://www.ralfebert.de/ios-examples/uikit/uitableviewcontroller/reorderable-cells/

I then save the updated set of items (first locally to Core Data in my app, and then push to CloudKit later...but you can do whatever makes the most sense for you).

Missing or duplicate position can easily be error handled when you build your tableview - but if you loop over each item on a move event, then you shouldn't have that issue either way.

Not sure I follow the 'merge' concerns issue - can you elaborate?

Comment: I talked to Apple technical support, and they said specifically not to do this. Specifically because of merge issues. What I mean by merge issue is, you are assuming that cloudkit is atomic for multi-record changes (for example, record1.pos=3, record2.pos=4 etc). But it is not. So if two devices reordered the same list, you can end up in a situation where you get half the sequence from each device.

Comment: makse sense - though for my scenario, reordering is done locally before saving to cloudkit - and the flow of the app means that once published to cloudkit, order is set.  But good to know they suggest against it.

Comment: @erotsppa what did apple say to do though? :)